# Adding images to a database using Core Data

Tags: ios, xcode, core-data, uiimage

Trying to add an image to a database using core data. A view controller is used for the user to enter text fields and an image to the database. The user selects an image using UIImagePickerController. Code is:

```
- (void) add
{
NSManagedObjectContext *context = [app managedObjectContext];

Exercises *exercises = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Exercises" inManagedObjectContext:context];

exercises.name = name.text;
exercises.difficulty = difficulty.text;
exercises.type = type.text;
exercises.instructions = instructions.text;
NSData* image1 = [NSData dataWithData:UIImagePNGRepresentation(imageView.image)];
[NSManagedObject setValue:image1 forKey:@"imageView"];

[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
```

Error is Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[ setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key imageView.' What should the key be? Am I even going about this the right way? By the way, saving and retrieving of text works fine. My only issue with adding images.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The call:

```
[NSManagedObject setValue:image1 forKey:@"imageView"];
```

attempts to call `setValue:forKey:` on the class `NSManagedObject`. That class does not implement that method so it raises an exception.

Probably you wanted to call it on `exercises`, the instance of `NSManagedObject` that you've just created — does it have a data attribute called `imageView`?

In both style and performance terms, the dot notation to access a specific setter is preferred, as you've used for all the other properties, but it's unlikely to be much of a problem compared to the PNG encode it sits next to so I wouldn't worry about it.

Comment: yes that was the solution, but I had a couple of errors. It works perfectly this way:               NSData* img= [NSData dataWithData:UIImagePNGRepresentation(imageView.image)];
[exercises.self setValue:img forKey:@"image1"]; Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

Try saving your image in document directory and add the path of image in the database.

You can access the Image using :

```
[[UIImageView alloc]initWithImage:[UIImage imageWithData:
    [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:@"PathStoredInDatabase"]]];
```